# Scala val and type at the same time

Tags: scala

While reading Scala source code i came across the following in `scala/package.scala`
I don't quite get why we need `trait` and `val` at the same time. The `trait` keyword will alias the class, then why do we need the `val` ?

```scala
  type StringBuilder = scala.collection.mutable.StringBuilder
  val StringBuilder = scala.collection.mutable.StringBuilder

  // Numeric types which were moved into scala.math.*

  type BigDecimal = scala.math.BigDecimal
  val BigDecimal = scala.math.BigDecimal

  type BigInt = scala.math.BigInt
  val BigInt = scala.math.BigInt

  type Equiv[T] = scala.math.Equiv[T]
  val Equiv = scala.math.Equiv
```

Am including a Generic Type example as well to get more understanding about the multiple declarations there was well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because `type` only defines a type alias; it doesn't alias the type's companion object.

The companion object usually contains handy methods, especially an `apply` method for creating objects of the type. If you don't do the `val`, you won't have access to those methods, at least not under the name of the alias.

Comment: Wow! Interesting, Intellij takes me to the class definition when i click on the `type` line and it takes me to the object definition when i click on the `val` line.